# Installing Skype on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: windows, audio, skype, amazon-ec2

For my application, I need to have Skype working on my Amazon EC2 Windows instance. I got the application installed and am able to log in, however, I can't make a phone call, since I am getting an 'Can't detect your sound card' error.

Since I'm trying to inject audio from an audio file into the phone call, I don't need the sound card on the server. Thus, I need a way to bypass this error message.

I have tried installing Virtual Audio Cable, which unfortunately didn't work (even though it worked on my desktop machine).

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the Windows Audio Service (and the dependent services as well):

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-the-audio-service-is-not-running-when-opening-the-volume-mixer-in-vista/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did enable this service and made sure that the dependencies are running as well.
Unfortunately, the Skype problem persists! It still can not detect a microphone so I am unable to make calls. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: version 3 doesn't work in windows 2008 server.

Did you try Virtual Audio Cable 3 instead of 4?

http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac3.htm